# Angular 2 circular dependency error solution equivalent to Angular 1 solution?

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

I'm using Angular 2, Typescript, Visual Studio 2015.

In angular 1 I wrote a logger that logs to the console and once http is available also sends certain logs to a webapi backend.  I used the config and run phases to set the http service once it's ready.  The log service uses it once it's set.

In Angular 2 the config and run are gone and I'm confused on how to accomplish the same thing.  I currently get circular dependancy errors as one would expect.  Can I not basically repeat the functionality I had before.  I messed around using the ReflectiveInjector to retrieve Http at a later time, but had problems with having to reference every dependency it need it seemed.

I would imagine something like this:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class MyLogService implements ILogService {
    public httpService: MyHttpWrapper = null;
    constructor(paramAService: AService
        ) {...}
    public info(message: string) {
        //once http is set the logger will actually send the message as well
        if (this.httpService != null){
            this.httpService.post("logurl", message);
        }
        console.info(message);
    }


@Injectable()
export class MyHttpWrapper extends Http {
    constructor(paramLogService: MyLogService 
    ) {
        paramLogService.info("my http service did something...") ;         
...
```

Is there a way to make my log service get the instance of my Http wrapper later in Angular 2 like I did in Angular 1?

I want the Http wrapper to be able to log as well, and the log service to be able to send its logs via http once http is fully configured.  This worked out fine with Angular 1.  I look at it like a delayed dependency usage on the log service's part ie. it won't actually use http until http is ready and has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using [forwardRef](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/forwardRef-function.html) to inject the http dependency. In your `MyLogService` inject `http` as

`@Inject(forwardRef(() => Http )) httpService: Http`

I have not tested this.

Comment: I saw this in the docs, but I doubt this can solve cycles in DI. What `forwardRef` can do, is to resolve cycles between classes within one file.

Comment: I agree, what I did in Angular 1 was set the Http related service into the log Service during the run phase.  forwardRef doesn't seem like it answers this circular dependency issue.

Comment: Ok, I have used it to resolve dependency when injecting parent component in child component, so i was assuming this can fix the cyclic issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to break up the cycle. 
This is a workaround that worked for me.

```ts
private http:Http;
constructor(/*private http:Http*/ injector:Injector) {
  setTimeout(() => this.http = injector.get(Http));
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and the Injector is showing as undefined in the constructor. Everything works otherwise, so I'm confused on why that happened.

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Never seen it mentioned that injecting the `Injector` caused any problems.

Comment: Interesting, the problem was that I used useFactory for my log service in the @NgModule decorator to provide number in the constructor.  When I changed it to just having the LogService in the AppModule's decorator's provide and removed the number constructor parameter the Injector showed up correctly.

Comment: If you add this code to your question I can have a look. From your explanation it's too difficult to know what's going on.

Comment: I'll update shortly with what I saw, after that if no one comes along with anything better I'll mark this correct.  The behavior with useFactory is a little troubling, but I think I can find an alternative on that.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me recently;

```
constructor( private injector: Injector ) {
    /** code */
}

public get yourService(): YourService {
    return this.injector.get( YourService );
}
```

then just use your service as `this.yourService.method();`